# Excel date function - unknown day or month

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

Not sure if what I want is possible (I'd imagine it isn't as Excel likes things to be correct!), but, I have a list of items, and the date to/from they were in use. In some cases, the day and/or month of that item is unknown. At present, I show this on my Excel as, for example, `dd/mm/2018`.

Obviously, I am then unable to filter on just the year as it isn't in correct date/time format.

So, is there anyway of storing dates with unknown days/months, but where Excel will still allowing filtering, as if it were a proper date?

Think that makes sense!

Example:

[image: Screenshot example]

Answer (score 0):

You can format a cell to show only the year.

Assuming that you have some date in the cell and only want
to display the year from that date.

- Select the cell or cells
- Right-click a selected cell and select "Format Cells"
- Click "Custom" on left side of the dialog
- Enter `aaaa` in the Type field
- Click OK.

With this visual difference in the display of the cells, you will be able
to see which cells don't have a full date. Once you update the full date
in the field, you may return the cell's format to be the same as the
ones that have full dates.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: To allow the use of the simplest method of sorting;
Set dates to be 01/01/year where month and date is unknown
and similarly 01 for day in dates where it is unknown (alt: possibly 28:th for end dates).

If you need to TELL which dates has unknown info, add a column  indicating it, e.g. "DM" for day and month, or just "D" for day.